# Can I install 10.04 on a Sandy Bridge box?

Tags: 10.04

If I have a new computer with Sandy Bridge processor. Does this mean I can only install Natty? Can the Lucid kernel run on Sandy Bridge? What will happen if I try installing 10.04 on a Sandy Bridge box?

Answer (score 1):

If you try an Ubuntu installation and it doesn't work you will still be able to install another operating system. Sandy bridge processors should run Ubuntu 10.04 fine so there is no reason to worry either way.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed Ubuntu 10.04 (64 bit) on a Sandy Bridge server, and it works like a charm.